# How to match keywords with SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a website that accepts user input keywords and output data that matches. For instance if the user specifies keyword as '`Restaurant pizza`' then my database should output such record.

My current table has a column called `category` and five columns named from `keyword1` to `keyword5` which contains their specialized area, i.e. 'pizza', 'chicken' or 'bbq' etc.

But I have no idea how to write the SQL query since user may input keywords in any order: category first or with specialized area first.

so such query will surely return no result (given that user input 'Restaurant pizza' for query):

```
SELECT * 
   FROM message 
 WHERE  category LIKE 'Restaurant pizza' 
 OR     keyword1 LIKE 'Restaurant pizza' 
 OR     keyword2 LIKE 'Restaurant pizza'
```

I guess it would be a bad idea splitting input keyword into words then running every word in the WHERE clause to database. but I really do not know how to achieve my goal.

In addition, would you please give me some advice on how to build index in this scenario?

Comment: Hi loudking, you need to use '%' with your 'LIKE' statements example : SELECT * FROM message WHERE category LIKE '%Restaurant pizza%' OR keyword1 LIKE '%Restaurant pizza%' OR keyword2 LIKE '%Restaurant pizza%'

Comment: If the User can input in any order. Then you will have to split and run the input's each word in the query. If you don't want to do that, you will have to inform the user to put it in a particular order before he enters. Its either of them. Cant do both of them.

Comment: @PKirby, I think you misunderstood. In the example `Restaurant pizza` given in the OP, Restaurant would be the category and pizza would be the keyword. `'%Restaurant pizza%'` would look for those which has both in same column. Also OP says its possible for the user to enter in any order, like `Pizza Restaurant` too.

Comment: seems you should split the string and run query for each combination or as single string... and based on the weight of each  words result should be displayed... **it may be resource consuming** ...there may be better approach..!!

Comment: "_My current table has a column called category and five columns named from keyword1 to keyword5 which contains their specialized area, i.e. 'pizza', 'chicken' or 'bbq' etc._" sounds like you gave yourself a hard time doing that :) Next time create a table `keywords` and a many-to-many link table from the `restaurants` to the `keywords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create `FULLTEXT` index on `category` and `keywords` columns, then when querying data explode query string by delimeters (space character) and then create query something like:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
  WHERE 
  MATCH (category,keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4,keyword5) 
  AGAINST ('pizza') 
  AND 
  MATCH (category,keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4,keyword5) 
  AGAINST ('restaurant');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM message  
WHERE `category` LIKE '%Restaurant%'  
AND (`keyword1` IN ('Pizza','chicken','bbq')  
OR `keyword2` IN ('Pizza','chicken','bbq'))
```